# Struggling with rewrite rule

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm struggling with a particular rewrite rule on apache.  More precise, I'm struggling to understand what's wrong with it.

I need to rewrite urls like so:

```
http://www.mysite.com/section/venue_info/123/name
or
http://www.mysite.com/section/venue_info/123/
or
http://www.mysite.com/section/venue_info/123

         |
         V

http://www.mysite.com/section/venue_info.php?id=123
```

Note that `section` is a variable in the equation.  In live site it can be one of a several values, so whatever section was supplied, I need to use that section.  I've got this in my apache config:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/trunk/publish
<Directory /var/www/site/publish/trunk/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^\/(\w+)\/venue_info\/(\d+)(\/.+|\/?)$ $1/venue_info.php?id=$2
</Directory>
```

However this doesn't match.  I've tried all sorts of variations, but no with no luck. What's the right `RewriteRule` here? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, figured it out!

Apparently, `mod_rewrite` directives would not work inside `<Directory>` element.  Once I placed them into `<Location>` block, everything worked just fine.  So now my apache config looks like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/site/trunk/publish
<Directory /var/www/site/publish/trunk/>
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks 
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

<Location "/">
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^\/(\w+)\/venue_info\/(\d+)(\/.+|\/?)$ $1/venue_info.php?id=$2
</Location>
```

And everything works just fine.